# Sql statement with like from variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm executing this code in python

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite

con = sqlite.connect("db.sqlite")
cur = con.cursor()
surname = "'%atton%'"
cur.execute("select id from singers where surname like :surname", locals())
cur.close()
con.close()
```

After this code `cur.rowcount == -1` but Patton is in the database.

Is my SQL statement bad?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DB-API parameterization you use (which you *should* use, don't change that) means the surname will automatically be quoted or escaped appropriately. You should remove the inner set of quotes from your `surname` string.

```
surname = "%atton%"
cur.execute("select id from singers where surname like :surname",
    dict(surname=surname))
```

Comment: The problem is still here. Nothing changed.

Comment: You'll have to expand on the problem then. What DB-API module are you using? What paramstyle does it use? Are you actually reading the result of the query? Does the DB-API module even bother setting rowcount properly?

Comment: "What paramstyle does it use?" What does this mean? "Are you .. query?" Yes, I'm reading the result `if cur.rowcount > 0:` , but this code is not executed. "Does ... properly?" Yes, I used it in another part of code and it works. The main problem is with `surname like :surname`. `surname = :surname` works.

Comment: `if cur.rowcount > 0` isn't "reading the result". `sqlite3` doesn't set the rowcount for these queries. You need to actually *fetch the results*, either by using one of the fetch* methods of the cursor object, or iterating over the cursor object itself.

Comment: @Thomas Wouters This works, could you send me a link where is this documented? And why you used `dict(surname=surname)` and how did you know to use "%atton%"? I haven't found this pitfalls on sqlite pages.

Comment: I use `dict()` because I prefer being explicit over relying on `locals()`, and I knew how to use "%atton%" because that's how DB-API parameterization works; any tutorial on the DB-API and how to use parameters should cover that. As for rowcount not being updated, http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount